# extracting items using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a a file which has the following :

```
new=['{"TES1":"=TES0"}}', '{"""TES1:IDD""": """=0x3C""", """TES1:VCC""": """=0x00"""}']
```

I am trying to extract the first item, TES1:=TES0 from the list. I am trying to use a regular expression to do this. This is what i tried but i am not able to grab the second item TES0.

```
import re
TES=re.compile('(TES[\d].)+')
for item in new:
    result = TES.search(item)
    print result.groups()
```

The result of the print was ('TES1:',). I have tried various ways to extract it but am always getting the same result. Any suggestion or help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Option (with quotes)**

To match `"TES1":"=TES0"`, you can use this regex:

```
"TES\d+":"=TES\d+"
```

like this:

```
match = re.search(r'"TES\d+":"=TES\d+"', subject)
if match:
    result = match.group()
```

**Second Option (without quotes)**

If you want to get rid of the quotes, as in `TES1:=TES0`, you use this regex:

Search: `"(TES\d+)":"(=TES\d+)"`

Replace: `\1:\2`

like this:

```
result = re.sub(r'"(TES\d+)":"(=TES\d+)"', r"\1:\2", subject)
```

**How does it work?**

```
"(TES\d+)":"(=TES\d+)"
```

- Match the character “"” literally `"`
- Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 `(TES\d+)`

  - Match the character string “TES” literally (case sensitive) `TES`
  - Match a single character that is a “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script) `\d+`

    - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
- Match the character string “":"” literally `":"`
- Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 `(=TES\d+)`

  - Match the character string “=TES” literally (case sensitive) `=TES`
  - Match a single character that is a “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script) `\d+`

    - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
- Match the character “"” literally `"`

  \1:\2
- Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1 `\1`
- Insert the character “:” literally `:`
- Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2 `\2`

Comment: awesome...thanks for taking your to explain in detail!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `findall`:

```
import re
TES=re.compile('TES[\d].')
for item in new:
    result = TES.findall(item)
    print result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single replacement, example:

```
import re

result = re.sub(r'{"(TES\d)":"(=TES\d)"}}', '$1:$2', yourstr, 1)
```